# VueJS detect when DOM is ready after using push() to add a new element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vueJS I have a `<table>`. if I click on a button a new row will get inserted in the table using

```
this.rows.push({
        title: '',
        price: ''
      });
```

The problem is that I am using this function:

```
$(".price").numeric({
        decimal: false,
        negative: false
      });
```

This is a jquery function that force inputs to only be integer.
So when a new row is added which has a input the above function no longer works.

If I add a new row and run

```
$(".u-price").numeric({
        decimal: false,
        negative: false
      });
```

It will make the new row only accept integers

I have also tried to do it all in once like this:

```
addRow() {
      this.rows.push({
        title: '',
        price: '',
      });
      $(".price").numeric({
        decimal: false,
        negative: false
      });
    },
```

To toggle the numeric helper right after but it doesnt work.
So how can I detect when a new row is added so I can run the numeric helper after?

Comment: Really what you should do is wrap whatever needs `numeric` in a component and use the `mounted` lifecycle handler to initialize it.

Comment: Wouldn't a directive work here? `inserted(el) {$(el).numeric(..)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a directive for this, as is.

```
Vue.directive('numeric', {
  inserted(el) {
    $(el).numeric({
      decimal: false,
      negative: false
    })
  }
})
```

In the template:

```
<input v-numeric type="text" />
```

[Working pen](https://codepen.io/luord/pen/dVaBGp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vue.nextTick()`. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

> In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a
> data change, you can use Vue.nextTick(callback) immediately after the
> data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been
> updated